# Getting contacts from phone is taking too much time

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working on an instant chat messaging application.I am getting contacts from phone and displayed them in list view of an activity.But it is taking 25-30 seconds.I am using the following code:

**1. On clicking Contact button:**

```
   contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contacts Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                ArrayList<Bean_PhoneNumbers> listBeanPhone = getContactsFromPhone();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SingleChatActivity.this, PhoneBookActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
                intent.putExtra("friendName", friendName);
                intent.putExtra("absoluteURL", completeURLFriend);
                intent.putExtra("friendID", frndID);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**2. getContactFromPhone() method**

```
 private ArrayList<Bean_PhoneNumbers> getContactsFromPhone() {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            bean_phoneNumbers = new Bean_PhoneNumbers();
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    // Toast.makeText(SingleChatActivity.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bean_phoneNumbers.setName(name);
                    bean_phoneNumbers.setPhoneNumber(phoneNo);
                    listBeanPhoneNumbers.add(bean_phoneNumbers);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }

        }
    }
    return listBeanPhoneNumbers;
}
```

**3.PhoneBookActivity.java**

```
    public class PhoneBookActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private ListView listView;
    private Adapter_PhoneBook adapter_phoneBook;
    private String friendName, completeURLFriend, frndID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phonebook);

        //findViewByID
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Fetching data from a parcelable object passed from SingleChatActivity
        ArrayList<Bean_PhoneNumbers> listBeanPhone = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("listBeanPhone");
        for (int i = 0; i < listBeanPhone.size(); i++) {
            Bean_PhoneNumbers bean = listBeanPhone.get(i);
            String name = bean.getName();
            Log.e("Name", name);
        }
        //Initialization
        adapter_phoneBook = new Adapter_PhoneBook(PhoneBookActivity.this, listBeanPhone);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter_phoneBook);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        //Getting values from previos screen(ChatFragment)
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        friendName = bundle.getString("friendsName", null);
        completeURLFriend = bundle.getString("absoluteURL", null);
        frndID = bundle.getString("friendID");


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Bean_PhoneNumbers bean_phoneNumbers = (Bean_PhoneNumbers) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneBookActivity.this, SingleChatActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("bean", bean_phoneNumbers);
                intent.putExtra("friendName", friendName);
                intent.putExtra("absoluteURL", completeURLFriend);
                intent.putExtra("friendID", frndID);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        adapter_phoneBook.getFilter().filter(s);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please review my code and tell me where i am doing wrong.I am getting contacts from phone and storing in an ArrayList.Then i am passing that arraylist to PhoneBookActivity which has a listview .I am population the listview using a BaseAdapter .

Comment: convert your array list in string then put in intent for transfer it on another activity.try once

Comment: if no success then fetch contact at first time from user's contact list and store it in sqlite. Because from the sqlite app can fetch data more easily. And also apply a condition when user update his contact list then sqlite become update to database table.

Comment: @MKJParekh: I have moved my question codereview .Please check it.

Comment: @MKJParekh : Thanks for giving your valuable time.

Comment: One simple tip, start using [`CursorAdapter`](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Loading-Contacts-with-Content-Providers)

Comment: Please help me to fix my issue.I am still struggling with it.It is taking too much time to load contacts .

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by using LoaderManager.Following is the code of my PhoneBookActivity.java

```
public class PhoneBookActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private SearchView searchView;
    private ListView listView;
    private Adapter_PhoneBook adapter_phoneBook;
    private String friendName, completeURLFriend, frndID, roomID, ownerID, group_members, group_name;
    private String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    private String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
    private Bean_PhoneNumbers bean_phoneNumbers;
    private List<Bean_PhoneNumbers> listBeanPhoneNumbers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phonebook);

        //findViewByID
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //Getting values from previos screen(ChatFragment)
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        friendName = bundle.getString("friendsName", null);
        // Log.e("FriendName",friendName);
        completeURLFriend = bundle.getString("absoluteURL", null);
        //Log.e("CompleteURLFriend",completeURLFriend);
        frndID = bundle.getString("friendID");
        //Log.e("FriendID",frndID);
        roomID = bundle.getString("GroupRoomID", null);
        ownerID = bundle.getString("owner_id", null);
        group_members = bundle.getString("group_members", null);
        group_name = bundle.getString("group_name", null);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bean_PhoneNumbers bean_phoneNumbers = (Bean_PhoneNumbers) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

                //On clicking list item ,we can move to either SingleChatActivity or GroupChatActivity
                //If PhoneBookActivity is started from SingleChatActivity
                if (friendName != null && completeURLFriend != null && frndID != null) {
                    Intent singleChatIntent = new Intent(PhoneBookActivity.this, SingleChatActivity.class);
                    singleChatIntent.putExtra("bean", bean_phoneNumbers);
                    singleChatIntent.putExtra("friendsName", friendName);
                    singleChatIntent.putExtra("absoluteURL", completeURLFriend);
                    singleChatIntent.putExtra("friendID", frndID);
                    startActivity(singleChatIntent);
                }

                //If PhoneBookActivity is started from GroupChatActivity
                if (roomID != null && ownerID != null && group_members != null && group_name != null) {
                    Intent groupChatIntent = new Intent(PhoneBookActivity.this, GroupChatActivity.class);
                    groupChatIntent.putExtra("bean", bean_phoneNumbers);
                    groupChatIntent.putExtra("GroupRoomID", roomID);
                    groupChatIntent.putExtra("group_members", group_members);
                    groupChatIntent.putExtra("group_name", group_name);
                    groupChatIntent.putExtra("owner_id", ownerID);


                    startActivity(groupChatIntent);
                }
            }
        });


        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        adapter_phoneBook.getFilter().filter(s);
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        listBeanPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            bean_phoneNumbers = new Bean_PhoneNumbers();
            bean_phoneNumbers.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME)));
            bean_phoneNumbers.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER)));
            listBeanPhoneNumbers.add(bean_phoneNumbers);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        adapter_phoneBook = new Adapter_PhoneBook(getApplicationContext(), listBeanPhoneNumbers);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter_phoneBook);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

This activity is called on clicking Contact icon in the Single Chat/Group Chat activity .

```
 contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contacts Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            popupWindow.dismiss();
           // ArrayList<Bean_PhoneNumbers> listBeanPhone = getContactsFromPhone();
            Intent intent = new Intent(GroupChatActivity.this, PhoneBookActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
           // intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listBeanPhone", listBeanPhone);
            intent.putExtra("GroupRoomID", roomID);
            intent.putExtra("group_members", group_members);
            intent.putExtra("group_name", group_name);
            intent.putExtra("owner_id", ownerID);
            Log.e("rID", roomID);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

The code is working for me now.Hope it will help for others as well .Happy coding :-)